# How to do calculations and then compare them in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2019

I have a table with columns `Recordnumber`, `Test`, `Value`, `Date` and `Complement`. `Recordnumber` and `test` are the primary key.

[image: Table with records]

I need compare values from TW01SS and TW01D1+TW01D2 with the same `Recordnumber` and depending on which value is bigger add it to `Complement` column. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: If TW01SS is bigger, what complement row should it update? In 2208011011+TW01SS 50 > 1+1 so 2208011011+TW01SS row, complement column should = 50? and if its the other way around, if D1+D2 > SS then update both D1 and D2 with a value?

Comment: If TW01SS > TW01D1+TW01D2 then in Complement should value of TW01SS and if TW01SS < TW01D1+TW01D2 then SUM of TW01D and TW01D2.

Comment: Great. Thanks, I think I understand what you want. I've posted an answer. In the future, please read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and update the question with table descriptions, data examples (in a table, not an image), and what you attempted so far. You can even include a Fiddle like I did in my answer below, it'll help you get an answer quickly.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data, please paste them in as text. Expected results would also help

Answer (score 0):

You can create two `CTE`'s, one to get the *SS count* and the other the *D1+D2 count* then `UPDATE` the `Complement` column by the `Recordnumber`.

See [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

> Specifies a temporary named result set, known as a common table
> expression (CTE). This is derived from a simple query and defined
> within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
> or MERGE statement. This clause can also be used in a CREATE VIEW
> statement as part of its defining SELECT statement. A common table
> expression can include references to itself. This is referred to as a
> recursive common table expression.

```
;WITH 
D1D2_Count
AS
-- Define D1+D2 Count CTE Query.
(
    SELECT RecordNumber AS D1D2_ID,
    SUM(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY RecordNumber) AS D1D2_Total
    FROM TestA 
    WHERE Test LIKE '%D1' OR Test LIKE '%D2'
    
),
SS_Count
AS
-- Define SS Count CTE Query.
(
    SELECT RecordNumber AS SS_ID,
    SUM(Value) OVER(PARTITION BY RecordNumber) AS SS_Total
    FROM TestA 
    WHERE Test LIKE '%SS'
)
UPDATE A 
SET Complement = 
     CASE WHEN D1D2_Total > SS_Total
      THEN D1D2_Total
      ELSE SS_Total
     END 
FROM TestA AS A
LEFT JOIN D1D2_Count ON RecordNumber = D1D2_ID
LEFT JOIN SS_Count ON RecordNumber = SS_ID
```

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f54f8297f7ad769f4bbc0d43e707449f).

Optionally, you can add a `WHERE` clause to the end of the `UPDATE` statement so that it'll only update the `Complement` that has the greater total

- If D1+D2 > SS, UPDATE Only the D1+D2 rows
- Otherwise, UPDATE Only the SS rows.

Like this:

```
WHERE Test LIKE 
     CASE WHEN D1D2_Total > SS_Total
      THEN '%D1'
      ELSE '%SS'
     END 
     OR Test LIKE 
     CASE WHEN D1D2_Total > SS_Total
      THEN '%D2'
      ELSE '%SS'
     END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, case when SS >= DX then SS else DX end
from T cross apply (values (
    sum(case when Test = 'TW01SS1' then Value end)
        over (partition by RecordNumber),
    sum(case when Test like 'TW01D[12]' then Value end)
        over (partition by RecordNumber))
) s(SS, DX);
```

You can use `else coalesce(DX, SS)` if null/missing tests are at play.

As an `update`:

```
update T
set Complement = (
    select case when SS >= DX then SS else DX end
    from T t2 cross apply (values (
        sum(case when Test = 'TW01SS1' then Value end),
        sum(case when Test like 'TW01D[12]' then Value end)
    ) s(SS, DX)
    where t2.RecordNumber = T.RecordNumber
);
```